# Filter resources by template variable value with MODx Wayfinder

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder

I have a site that uses Wayfinder to display the latest 3 entries from an Articles blog. Now, I want to only consider those blog entries that are tagged `Highlights`.

My original Wayfinder call looks like this, nothing spectacular:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`296` &level=`1`
    &outerTpl=`emptyTpl`
    &innerTpl=``
    &rowTpl=`thumbnails_formatter`
    &ignoreHidden=`1`
    &sortBy=`menuindex`
    &sortOrder=`DESC`
    &limit=`3`
    &cacheResults=`0`
]]
```

as Articles tags are managed via the `articlestags` TV, I thought that a `&where` might do the trick, but with no luck yet:

```
&where=`[{"articlestags:LIKE":"%Highlights%"}]`
```

does not yield anything. As a sanity check, I tried `[{"pagetitle:LIKE":"%something%"}]`, which worked. Obviously, the problem is that `articlestags` is not a column of `modx_site_content`, but I'm not sure about how to put the subquery.

```
SELECT contentid
FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
WHERE tmplvarid=17
  AND value LIKE '%Highlights%'
```

Gave me the right IDs on the sql prompt, but adding it to the Wayfinder call like this gave an empty result again:

```
&where=`["id IN (SELECT contentid FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues WHERE tmplvarid=17 AND value LIKE '%Highlights%')"]`
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'd like to stay with Wayfinder for consistency, but other solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little playing around led me to a solution: I needed to include the class name (not table name) when referring to the ID:

```
&where=`["modResource.id IN (SELECT contentid FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues WHERE tmplvarid=17 AND value LIKE '%Highlights%')"]`
```

a small test showed that even a simple

```
&where=`["id = 123"]`
```

does not work without `modResource.`.

A look at `wayfinder.class.php` shows the following line, which seems to be the "culprit":

```
$c->select($this->modx->getSelectColumns('modResource','modResource'));
```

This method aliases the selected columns - relevant code is in `xpdoobject.class.php`. The first parameter is the class name, the second a table alias. The effect is that the query selects `id AS modResource.id`, and so on.

---

**EDIT:** final version of my query:

```
&where=`["modResource.id IN (
    SELECT val.contentid
    FROM modx_site_tmplvars AS tv
    JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS val
     ON tv.id = val.tmplvarid
    WHERE tv.name = 'articlestags' AND (
        val.value = 'Highlights'
     OR val.value LIKE 'Highlights,%'
     OR val.value LIKE '%,Highlights'
     OR val.value LIKE '%,Highlights,%'
    )
)"]`
```

I don't claim this query is particularly efficient (I seem to recall that OR conditions are bad). Also, MODx won't work with this one if the newlines aren't stripped out. Still, I prefer to publish the query in its well-formatted form.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [pdomenu](http://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdomenu) (part of [pdoTools](http://modx.com/extras/package/pdotools)) instead Wayfinder

```
[[!PdoMenu? 
    &startId=`296` 
    &level=`1`
    &outerTpl=`emptyTpl`
    &innerTpl=``
    &rowTpl=`thumbnails_formatter`
    &ignoreHidden=`1`
    &sortBy=`menuindex`
    &sortOrder=`DESC`
    &limit=`3`
    &cacheResults=`0`

    &includeTVs=`articlestags`
    &where=`[{"TVarticlestags.value:LIKE":"%filter%"}]`

]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I prefer not to install additional plugins right now, but it seems rather versatile. The extra page shows "9 Likes, 56 Dislikes", though. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: This is not plugins, its just some useful snippets. Most of the documentation in Russian, is why so many of dislikes, but if you look at the source code ( https://github.com/bezumkin/pdoTools/ ) and understand how it works, they are very hard to help you in develop

Comment: ah, terminology mishap! I meant plugin as in "something installed via the package manager" I see, the language barrier is surely an issue. I'll keep pdoTools in mind, should I have query problems again in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at some of the config files [core/components/wayfinder/configs ] - I have not tried it, but it looks as if you can run your select query right in the config & pass the tmplvarid array to the $where variable.

Comment: if I get you right, what you suggest is similar to `&where='["id IN [[!runMyQuery]]"]'` (backticks replaced), just that the query is run in a config.php instead of a snippet.php, and the where is also set in the config instead of in the wayfinder call?

Comment: Pretty much exaclty, but without the extra snippets etc. In fact, you might just be able to get the modResource array using the TV values as criteria, though I am not sure if you would have to join the TV vars tables in the criteria as well [I'm not sure if they are a part of the modResource object ~ you would need to check]

Answer (score 0):

I used snippet as a parameter for the includeDocs of wayfinder, In my case it was useful because I was need different resources in menu depend on user browser (mobile or desktop)

```
[[!Wayfinder? 
    &startId=`4`
    &level=`1`
    &includeDocs=`[[!menu_docs?&startId=`4`]]`
    &outerTpl=`home_menu_outer`
    &rowTpl=`menu_row`
]]
```

and then menu_docs snippet

```
<?php
if (empty ($startId))
    return;

if (!isMobileDevice())
    return;


$query = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$query->innerJoin('modTemplateVarResource','TemplateVarResources');
$query->where(array(
    'TemplateVarResources.tmplvarid' => 3,
    'TemplateVarResources.value:LIKE' => 'yes',
    'modResource.parent' => $startId,
    'modResource.deleted' => 0,
    'modResource.published' => 1,
    'modResource.hidemenu' => 0
));
$resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $query);

$ouput = array();
foreach ($resources as $resource)
    $output[] = $resource->get('id');

return implode (',', $output);
```